# After `su user`, getting `fatal: failed to stat : Permission denied` with `git push`

Tags: git, stat

There's a lot of **setup** for this question:

I've got a host (`rpi5.local`) with 2 user accounts: `pi` and `cake`.

I wanted to explore `git`, and I created the `cake` account to "own" the "server/origin" repos. As user `cake`, in `/home/cake`, I created a folder (`git-srv`) with a sub-folder called `projectA`. I went through the process of initializing this repo using `git init --bare`.

Initially, I "populated" the `projectA` repo on the server from another host (`rpi4b.local`). I `push`ed some files in a folder called `Aproject` on the `raspberrypi4b.local` host to the `projectA` repo via SSH using this sequence:

```bash
$ hostname
rpi4b.local
$ pwd
/home/pi/Aproject
$ git push -u ssh://git@rpi5.local/home/cake/git-srv/projectA.git
```

This worked fine.

As user `pi`, I `clone`d the `projectA` repo to a folder in `/home/pi/XYZ`. I made & `commit`ed some changes to one of the files in `/home/pi/XYZ`, and attempted to `push` those changes to the server as follows:

```bash
$ hostname
rpi5.local
$ pwd
/home/pi/XYZ
$ git push -u /home/cake/git-srv/projectA.git
```

I got an error from this effort:

```
...
error: remote unpack failed: unable to create temporary object directory
To /home/cake/git-srv/projectA.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/cake/projectA.git'
```

After a bit of research on this error, I concluded it was a *permissions* issue between `pi` and `cake`. I *figured* the solution would be to `su cake` as user `pi`, and so I did that, and tried the `push` again. And finally, my question:

```
$ whoami
cake
$ hostname
rpi5.local
$ pwd
/home/pi/XYZ
$ git push -u /home/cake/git-srv/projectA.git
fatal: failed to stat '/home/pi/motd.git': Permission denied
```

What does `failed to stat` mean in this situation, and is there a straightforward *work-around*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Failed to stat” means that a call to [`stat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) returned an error, *i.e.* that the user running `git` doesn’t have permissions to obtain information on `/home/pi/motd.git`. That’s presumably because the `cake` user doesn’t have access to `/home/pi`.

Instead of trying to find the right set of permissions in this case, I think the most straightforward approach is to use SSH again (even though it’s the same system): `git push ssh://git@localhost:/home/cake/git-srv/projectA.git` or `git push ssh://cake@localhost:git-srv/projectA.git`.

Comment: "use SSH" - yes, I wondered about that. Should've tried it I guess.